# Select events having only start and end dates in mysql

Tags: mysql, select

I have a table in Mysql where i store the dayoff of my employee. 
The table have this structure:

```
Name | vacation_date_start | vacation_time_start |  vacation_date_end  | vacation_time_end
```

Obvivssly the start and the end day can be only one day but could also be different, for example:

```
Name | vacation_date_start | vacation_time_start |  vacation_date_end  | vacation_time_end
E1   |  2018-05-15         |      00:00:01       |       23:59:59      |      2018-05-15
E2   |  2018-05-01         |      00:00:01       |      23:59:59       |      2018-05-30
E3   |  2018-05-05         |      00:00:01       |      23:59:59       |      2018-05-20
```

Supposing that today is the may 15, I want a query that let me select all the employee that today are in vacation.
If I use a query like

```
SELECT * FROM `events` WHERE `date_start` = '2018-05-15'
```

I will see only the E1.

How can I see also the other 2 employee?

P.S: I haven't access to the software that write into this table so I can't edit the way in which is writes in the DB

Comment: Do yourself a HUGE favour. Store date and time as a single entity. Also, note that you have jumbled up dates and times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use between

```
SELECT * 
FROM `events` 
WHERE '2018-05-15' BETWEEN vacation_date_start  AND vacation_date_end
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6874d1/1)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT * FROM `events` WHERE `date_start` <= '2018-05-15' AND `date_end` >= '2018-05-15'
```

Comment: the problem is that with this I see other events that I don't need.